# Send and Receive from .NET to a Serial Device "Like" a VT 100

Tags: c#, .net, vt100

I have a serial device that is designed to receive and reply to commands from a VT100 type terminal. I can use any number of 'terminal emulators' to operate this device. But what I WANT to do is send a series of commands from a .NET Windows application and receive the replies back the same application so that I can drive a GUI that will be 'dirt simple' for the operators. What I don't want is another Terminal Emulator. It appears that using "System.IO.Serial.SerialPort" I can open a connection, send a message, assign a delegate to receive a message, actually receive a message...but the message that I send (a command) is not interpreted as I expect (when I inspect the status of the device with a terminal emulator the status does not match the command sent via .Net) and the message I receive back is not in a format I can decipher.

What I believe I need to do is properly encode the command and properly decode the response...but I can find no documentation that clearly explains how to do this.

(I'm working in C#, but any .Net example would be appreciated)

The code I am working with to prototype this is:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace busmanager
{
    public class buslink
    {
        SerialPort _serialPort;
        Boolean _echo;
        Delegate _receiver;

        //Defaut Ctor:
        public buslink(Delegate Receiver)
        {
            String[] SerialPorts = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            if (SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length > 0)
            {
                SetChannel(PortDefinitions.GetDefaults(SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0]), Receiver);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to serial port");
            }
        }

        //Custom Ctor: for externally defined PortDefinitions
        public buslink(PortDefinitions PortDefinitions, Delegate Receiver)
        {
            SetChannel(PortDefinitions, Receiver);
        }

        private void SetChannel(PortDefinitions PortDefinitions, Delegate Receiver)
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort()
            {
                PortName = PortDefinitions.PortName,
                //BaudRate = PortDefinitions.BaudRate,
                Parity = PortDefinitions.Parity,
                StopBits = PortDefinitions.StopBits,
                DataBits = PortDefinitions.DataBits,
                Handshake = PortDefinitions.Handshake,
                ReadTimeout = PortDefinitions.ReadTimeout,
                WriteTimeout = PortDefinitions.WriteTimeout,
                NewLine = "\n",
                Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII,
                DtrEnable = true,


            };
            _echo = PortDefinitions.Echo;
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
            _serialPort.Open();
            _receiver = Receiver;

        }

        void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] c = new byte[1000];
           int x = _serialPort.Read(c,0,1000);
            string d = c.ToString();

            _receiver.DynamicInvoke(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
        }

        public string Send(string Cmd)
        {
            Cmd = Cmd.ToUpper();
            byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Cmd);
            try
            {
                if (ValidateCmd(Cmd))
                {
                    _serialPort.WriteLine(Cmd);
                    if (_echo)
                    {
                        return "ECHO: " + Cmd;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return string.Empty;

        }

        private bool ValidateCmd(string Cmd)
        {
            return true;
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            _serialPort.Close();
            _serialPort.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public struct PortDefinitions
    {
        public string PortName { get; set; }
        public int BaudRate { get; set; }
        public Parity Parity { get; set; }
        public StopBits StopBits { get; set; }
        public int DataBits { get; set; }
        public Handshake Handshake { get; set; }
        public int ReadTimeout { get; set; }
        public int WriteTimeout { get; set; }
        public bool Echo { get; set; }

        public static PortDefinitions GetDefaults(string PortName)
        {
            return new PortDefinitions()
                                        {
                                            PortName = PortName.ToUpper(),
                                            BaudRate = 9600,
                                            Parity = Parity.None,
                                            StopBits = StopBits.One,
                                            DataBits = 8,
                                            Handshake = Handshake.None,
                                            ReadTimeout = 1000,
                                            WriteTimeout = 1000,
                                            Echo = true
                                        };
        }


    }


}
```

> The device is proprietary, but the commands it accepts are: `InX` `OutY`
>   (where X and Y are ports on the device and a connection is created
>   between the In and the Out Ports) `Status All` (shows the status of all
>   the inputs

Comment: What code are you using for this? Please post it, and also any information you have about the device to which you are connecting. Ie baud rates, data bits, stop bits, etc.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking to a device that is expecting to talk to a VT100, so you are writing code that is essentially pretending to be a VT100, right? You should show us the code you have along with the actual bytes that are sent/received and what you think they should mean.

Comment: @Gabe, correct I am trying to create an app that will 'emulate' a VT 100 at the backend (with a limited scope of valid commands) and a simple UI for users...

Comment: +1 for mentioning "VT100"

Comment: You need to post what bytes you are sending and what you are receiving.

Comment: @Gabe, At this point "nothing" works. I have try various values of X/Y from the example above, I have tried a variety of options, but the _serial.WriteLine(Cmd) where Cmd is a string of 'valid commands' like In 1 Out1 (valid values are 0-F for each X and Y) as well as Status All. These "Work" from the terminal emulator but not in the .Net code, which is why I suspect I need to format them differently, perhaps with a wrapper of some sort to tell the device "this is a command" I have tried adding "/n" and "/r/n" since you corrected me on the EOL but still the command does not affect the device.

Comment: Change it to use `Write` intead of `WriteLine` and manually add `\r\n` for newlines, then post the actual bytes (either in decimal or hex) sent and received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your newline definition set wrong. You have `NewLine = "/N"`, but you almost certainly need it to be `"\r\n"` or `"\n"`.

Comment: Thanks...I appreciate the correction on this point but it does not appear to resolve my issue.

Comment: @CosCallis: Which values didn't work? I know `/N`, but what else?

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help on this. Discovered that the issues was not the command set, but rather the rate at which the commands were being sent. The device couldn't handle the flow.